# A puzzling observation by Bradley Efron in his article in Science regarding Bayes’ Theorem in the 21st Century

Tags: bayesian, false-discovery-rate

Mr. Effron has published an interesting article in Science magazine with the enticing title "Bayes'
 Theorem in the 21st Century".  The article is quite short and can be found here: http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/Science-2013-Efron.pdf

Mr. Efron present a case where 6,033 cases of genes are examined and 28 out of them have a z score higher than 3.4.  He then make the following statements:

> “The determining fact here is that if indeed all the genes were Null,
>   we would expect only 2.8 z-values exceeding 3.40, that is, only 10% of
>   the actual number observed.  This brings us back to Bayes. Another
>   interpretation of the FDR algorithm is that the Bayesian probability
>   of nullness given a z-value exceeding 3.40 is 10%.”

To begin with the probability of z > 3.4 is 0.00034 in the standard normal distribution.  Therefore we would expect on average 6,033 x 0.00034 = 2.03 genes out of the 6,033 genes to have z > 3.4 assuming that all of those were Null.  Why Mr. Efron raises this number to 2.8?

Now let’s assume that 2.8 is the correct value and continue with Mr. Efron’s argument.  Mr. Efron says that the “Bayesian probability of nullness given a z-value exceeding 3.40 is 10%.”

How he defines the Bayesian probability in this case?  In general the Bayesian Theorem states that P(A|B) = P(A) * P(B|A)/P(B), where A and B are Events.  How he defines A and B in this context and how he assigns probabilities to them?

I took a different tack and reasoned as follows:  Given Null to be true the probability p of an observation with z > 3.4 is p = 0.00034.  Then the number of observations with z > 3.4 under the Null when the Sample is 6,033 can be viewed as the number of Successes in 6,033 trials where each Success has probability 0.00034.  This number is modeled by the Binomial Distribution with p = 0.0034 and size = 6,033.  Using the Binomial Distribution one can show that the probability of observing 28 cases with z > 3.4 in a Sample of 6,033 examples is practically zero and certainly much less than 10%.

I would greatly appreciate your response.

Comment: `the probability of z > 3.4 is 0.00034` - wow that's quite remarkable.

Comment: If you're remarking on the fact that $P(Z>t) = 10^{-k} t$ for some $t$ and some $k$, then there's rather a lot of such remarkable facts. Consider $k= \log_{10}t-\log_{10}(S(t))$  where $S(t) = 1-F(t)$ is the survivor function.

Comment: `> 2 * pnorm(abs(3.4), lower.tail=FALSE) 
[1] 0.00067386`